# create multimentional array in php

Tags: php

I try to create a multimentional array , I have a list of title

```
$array_title = array(
   "fey palin" => 3,
   "big theory" => 3, 
   "nyc through" => 3,
   "jonas storm" => 3, 
   "bang theory" => 3,
   "bang big" => 3,
   "storm test" => 3, 
   "plain sahra" => 3,
   "mind woolf"  => 3,
   "mind virginia" => 3
);
```

and I want to create a subarray if I find a link between two title for example  big theory and bang theory are link by the word "theory"

Here my full code :

```
$array_title = array(
    "fey palin" => 3,
    "big theory" => 3,
    "nyc through" => 3, 
    "jonas storm" => 3,
    "bang theory" => 3,
    "bang big" => 3,
    "storm test" => 3 , 
    "plain sahra" => 3,
    "mind woolf"  => 3,
    "mind virginia" => 3
);



$new_array = array();

$i = 0;

foreach($array_title as $title => $value){

    if(count($new_array) > 0){

        $words = explode(' ',$title);

        if(preg_grep ('/\b('.$words[0].'|'.$words[1].')\b/i', $new_array)){

            $result = preg_grep ('/\b('.$words[0].'|'.$words[1].')\b/i', $new_array);
            reset($result);
            $first_key = key($result);
            $new_array[$first_key][] = $title;

        }else{

            $new_array[$i] = $title;

        }
    }else{

        $new_array[$i] = $title;
    }

    $i++;
}
```

it s seems i cant do that
                $new_array[$first_key][] = $title;

I have an error which is:

> [] operator not supported for strings

Edit : I changed my code a bit but I have some duplicate value

Here is my updated code

```
$array_title = array("fey palin" => 3 , "big theory" => 3 , "nyc through" => 3 , 
                        "bang theory" => 3 , "jonas storm" => 3  , "bang big" => 3 ,
                        "storm test" => 3 , "plain sahra" => 3 ,"mind woolf"  => 3, "mind virginia" => 3);



$new_array = array();

foreach($array_title as $title => $value){
    $words = explode(' ',$title);
    if(count($new_array)  > 0){
        foreach($new_array as $key => $value){
            if(preg_match('/\b('.$words[0].'|'.$words[1].')\b/', $key)){
                $new_array[$key][$title] = $title;

            }else{
                if(count($value) > 0){
                    foreach($value as $val){
                        if(preg_match('/\b('.$words[0].'|'.$words[1].')\b/', $val)){
                            $new_array[$key][$title] = $title;
                        }
                    }              
                }else{
                    $new_array[$title] = array();

                }
            }
        }
    }else{
        $new_array[$title] = array();
    }
}
```

and the output:

Array
(
    [fey palin] => Array
        (
        )

```
[big theory] => Array
    (
        [bang theory] => bang theory
        [bang big] => bang big
    )

[nyc through] => Array
    (
    )

[bang theory] => Array              << To remove
    (
        [bang big] => bang big
    )

[jonas storm] => Array
    (
        [storm test] => storm test
    )

[bang big] => Array
    (
    )

[storm test] => Array             << To remove
    (
    )

[plain sahra] => Array
    (
    )

[mind woolf] => Array
    (
        [mind virginia] => mind virginia
    )

[mind virginia] => Array
    (
    )
```

)

Comment: you can try to create the value to be array first:$new_array[$first_key] = []; before the line $new_array[$first_key][] = $title;

Comment: Please show the output you want to have, based on the example data you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Add this statement before the one that triggers the error:

```
if (!isset($new_array[$first_key])) $new_array[$first_key] = array();
```

This way you ensure that `$new_array[$first_key]` is initialised as an array and you can safely add elements to that array.

But your algorithm will still fail, as you use that same array *$new_array* in your *preg_grep* call. That will not work as you want when you have added sub-arrays to *$new_array*.

You need to two variables: one for doing the *preg_grep*, which you do not change, and one where you add to in your loop. Currently you are mixing these two...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
$new_array[$i] = $title;
```

This is setting the initial elements of `$new_array` to strings, not an array. So when you later do

```
$new_array[$first_key][] = $title;
```

it's trying to do `array_push` on a string.

That line should be:

```
$new_array[$i] = array($title);
```